# How to get Parse objectId of clicked item on ion-item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

Hi I'm new to this ionic framework and angularJS. I've learnt to use Parse for storing data. I have made code for displaying my items from Parse Query to ion-item using ion-item with ng-repeat. Here is my view code :

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="trip in trips.results" ng-click="getDetail()">
<h2 >{{trip.attributes.title}}</h2 >
<p><span am-time-ago="trip.attributes.created"></span></p>
<p>{{trip.attributes.owner}}</p>
</br>
<p>{{trip.attributes.location}}</p>
<p>{{trip.attributes.price}} <!--| currency:"Rp"--></p>
</ion-item >
```

service for trip :

```
app.service("TripService", function ($q, AuthService) {
var self={
'load': function () {
        self.isLoading = true;
        var d = $q.defer();

        // Initialise Query
        var Trip = Parse.Object.extend("Trip");
        var tripQuery = new Parse.Query(Trip);
        tripQuery.descending('created');
        tripQuery.notEqualTo("owner", "all");

        // Perform query
        tripQuery.find({
            success: function (results) {
                angular.forEach(results, function (item) {
                    var trip = new Trip(item);
                    self.results.push(trip)
                });
                console.debug(self.results);

                // Check if its in the end of the list
                if (results.length == 0) {
                    self.hasMore = false;
                }

                // Finished
                d.resolve();
            }
        });
```

and call the load in the controller. It works perfectly and shown all items in Trip query.

What I want to do is :

--When I clicked on one of the items, it will go to the tripdetail page and shown all detail of the selected trip. I have tried few ways to pass parameters but it return undefined. How do I pass the parameter of clicked items to my controller? And how I use it in the tripdetail page?

EDIT:
Here is my config for the detail page when I try use *href="#/app/home/{{trips.detail.objectId}}"*:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    })

    .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
   'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'TripListCtrl'
    }
    }
})
    .state('app.home.detail', {
    url: '/home/:tripId',
    views: {
   'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/trip.html',
    controller: 'TripListCtrl'
    }
    }
})
```

};

Comment: Show what you tried that didn't work. You need to pass in `trip` as argument

Comment: Hi charlietfl, i have tried use <ion-item ng-repeat="trip in trips.results" href="#/home/{{trip.attributes.objectId}}"> before, but it returns me to index page.

Comment: so is that a valid route in your routing config? Is the href correct when compiled?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my question so it show my config. Maybe you can see where I did wrong

Comment: I don't know ionic well...does `item` even allow an href?

Comment: I'm new in ionic as well, but I have tried using href to navigate to dummy page that I made an it works.

Comment: ok..you have main parent url as `app` and child states so try `#/app/home/1234`. When you have child states their url also includes parent path. Also change `'app.home.detail'` to `'app.detail'` for now otherwise you have another nested child below `home` which would be `app/home/home/1234`

Comment: Hi charlietfl I have use ur suggestion. It works, I mean when I click the item it will open 'detail.html'. But the url shown is 'http://localhost:8100/#/app/home/' it doesnt return the title.attributes.objectId. I think it's something to do with the Parse database. Maybe you have some suggestion?Many thanks!

Comment: i can't really help without seeing if `title.attributes.objectId` is defined or not

Comment: `.objectId` is the problem.  Replace with `.id`

Comment: I tried using ' {{trip.attributes.id}} ' and my url still same as  ' localhost:8100/#/app/home/ '